# Date format issue in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

In Our `package` we had `where` clause like below.

```
 pp.start_date >= nvl(TO_DATE('01-JAN-2018', 'RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), pp.start_date)
```

It was working perfectly in customer environment. But since format was `'RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'` so we changed the date like below.

```
pp.start_date >= nvl(TO_DATE('2018/01/01', 'RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), pp.start_date)
```

Ideally it should work because we have given proper format. in the first case it is returning 679 rows but in second case it is returning 0 rows. 679 correct number of rows we have.

What is wrong with second NVL command?

Comment: Technically I don't think `RRRR` is a valid modifier. `RR` was intended to round a 2-digit year up or down to get the correct century. If you already have a 4-digit year, then use `YYYY`.

Comment: I checked with YYYY also RR but output is coming only when I am using date in DD-MON-YYYY format.

Comment: Please, provide reproducible example. What you are talking about is not correct either technically, or logically. If `RRRR` gives you *something* it doesn't guarantee that it is correct

Comment: I can't see how `TO_DATE('01-JAN-2018','RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')` could possibly be "working perfectly". That gives me `20-JAN-2001 18:00:00`. Also, why would you hardcode any `TO_DATE` expression when you could use a standard [date literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I see it, both are wrong.

If date value is `2018/01/01`, then its format is (I presume) `yyyy/mm/dd` (could be `yyyy/dd/mm` as well, can't tell just by looking at it). Where did `hh24:mi:ss` format come from? You never used it.

Therefore, I'd use date literal (which is always `date 'yyyy-mm-dd'`)(as you aren't interested in time component anyway):

```
where pp.start_date >= date '2018-01-01'
```

No `NVL` function. Why? Because date literal can't be `NULL`.

---

You *would* use `NVL` if it were about some other column, e.g.

```
where pp.start_date >= nvl(a.some_date, date '2018-01-01')
```

which means: if `a.some_date` column is `NULL` use `date '2018-01-01'` instead.

---

[EDIT] If there is time component, after all, use `TO_DATE` function with appropriate format mask, e.g.

```
where pp.start_date >= to_date('2018-01-01 23:09', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi')
```

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot. Actually date and time is coming from UI. whatever date customer will set, our query will load data from that date.so date/time automatically coming. if we want to keep time, what we should do?

Comment: You're welcome. If there are both date AND time involved, use TO_DATE (see edited answer).

Comment: What is logical reason of failing second condition but not first one? I mean second not returning any rows. Asking because, i have to give justification to customer.

Comment: What is PP.START_DATE's datatype?

Comment: it is date datatype. Customer is using 11g.

Comment: If it is DATE, then you have to compare it to another DATE (either it is a DATE datatype column, DATE literal, SYSDATE function, value returned by the TO_DATE function). As you used TO_DATE, then the only "answer" to your question is that you have to use appropriate format mask along with value you provide to the function. If it is e.g. 2018-01-23, then format mask must be YYYY-MM-DD, can't be MM.DD.YYYY nor RRRR-DD-MM nor DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS nor anything else but format that **exactly** matches the value.

Answer (score 3):

If you do:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE('01-JAN-2018', 'RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
FROM   DUAL;
```

Then, from the [string-to-date conversion rules](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF51090):

- `RRRR` also matches `RR` which matches `01`, so the year is 2001.
- `MM` also matches `MON` which matches `JAN`.
- `DD` matches `20`.
- `HH24` matches `18`.
- So the date generated is `2001-01-20 18:00:00`

If you use:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE('2018/01/01', 'RRRR/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
FROM   DUAL;
```

Then :

- `RRRR` matches `2018`.
- `MM` matches `01`.
- `DD` matches `01`.
- So the date generated is `2018-01-01 00:00:00`

*sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2d700af/465)*

You are generating two completely different dates almost 17 years apart.

> In the first case it is returning 679 rows but in second case it is returning 0 rows. 679 correct number of rows we have.

In the first case, you are getting 679 rows that are after `2001-01-20T18:00:00`.

In the second case, you are getting 0 rows that are after `2018-01-01T00:00:00`.

Given that the dates used were `01-JAN-2018` and `2018-01-01`, respectively, I would argue that the second is correct and you should be getting 0 rows and not 679 rows.